# Quantifying reactivity in substrates and electrophiles

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

What is "quantitative treatment of reactivity in substrates and electrophiles"?
I read about it in Jerry March's Advanced Organic Chemistry textbook, but I'm finding it difficult to comprehend.

Answer (score 2):

One large body of work aiming to quantify electrophilicity was accumulated by the [Mayr group](http://www.cup.lmu.de/oc/mayr/). Numerous reagents were tested against typical substrates, recording the kinetic rate constants allowed to attribute electrophilicity / nucleophilicity along the equation of

$$ \log k (\pu{20 ^\circ{}C}) = s_N (N + E) $$

with 
$E$ = electrophilicity parameter 
$N$ = nucleophilicity parameter 
$s_N$ = nucleophile-specific sensitivity parameter

Beside the selection of publication mentioned on the group page, work was invested to create a [map](http://www.cup.lmu.de/oc/mayr/ReactScalesPoster.pdf), and a public [database](http://www.cup.lmu.de/oc/mayr/reaktionsdatenbank/) with currently "1075 nucleophiles and 276 electrophiles".

Comment: So, testing various possible electrophiles on a given aromatic system, and quantifying the rates of reaction for each reaction is what you meant ?

Comment: @VishnuHaveri Yes, I did mean as *one* way to quantify electrophilicity.  An other, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrophile, is the electrophilicity index $\omega$, as fraction of the square of electronegativity ($\chi^2$), and chemical hardness ($\eta{}$). This second approach leaves kinetics, and solvent dependency  on nucleopilicity or electrophilicty of "the Mayr approach" out.